# Did Clausewitz's On War influence later non military/political philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Clausewitz's *On War* has influenced countless politicians and people with military related jobs.

> Did *On War* influence later non military/political
> philosophy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Gephon

One, perhaps unexpected influence exerted by Clausewitz on political theorising was on Marxist thinking. Lenin gave a particular turn to Clausewitz's dictum that 'war is simply the continuation of politics by other means' - the First World War was simply the continuation of *capitalist* politics by other (violent) means.

Here's an extract from an article that spells things out a little:

> Lenin's contribution [to Clausewitz's influence] has been more than adequately documented.
> Principally, it consisted in popularizing Clausewitz's formula regarding the relationship between policy and war and in giving
> Clausewitz the official stamp of Marxist legitimacy ...  During late 1914 or early 1915, in his Swiss
> exile, Lenin borrowed the first edition of Clausewitz's On War from
> Berne's public library. Evidently he was much impressed by the
> book. As was his habit, he copied long extracts from the German into a special notebook, underlining words, passages and ideas of
> particular importance and adding numerous annotations in Russian.
> Apart from a few passing comments on other matters, he concentrated overwhelmingly on two themes. One was the dialectic of
> defence and attack; the other - far more extensive and encompassing
> about two-thirds of his notebook - was **the function of war as
> a political instrument**, its overall dependence on political and
> social conditions, and, consequently, its continuous transformation
> through history. His many favourable comments on Clausewitz's
> formulae regarding the relationship between policy and war are much
> quoted. But he also seized with enthusiasm on all the passages in
> which Clausewitz demonstrated the historical nature of war (On War,
> I, 1, para. 27; VII, 30; VIII, 3 and 6B). 'To each epoch - its own
> wars', he wrote in the margins.

> Lenin read Clausewitz for a purpose and put him to immediate use.
> **With the outbreak of the first world war and the collapse of socialist
> solidarity, he directed all his efforts to denouncing the leaders of the
> Second International who, for the cause of national self-defence, had
> forsaken their previous commitment against war. In his pamphlets,
> arguing that the war was nothing but a capitalist war, waged by the
> capitalist states and ruling classes for the advancement of their
> interests**, he repeatedly used Clausewitz's famous dictum as a sharp
> weapon.

Azar Gat, 'Clausewitz and the Marxists: Yet Another Look', Journal of Contemporary History , Apr., 1992, Vol. 27, No. 2 (Apr., 1992), pp.
363-382: 370-1.